# SEO - 301 redirect via 404 page

Tags: seo, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I am new to this so I will try to explain myself clearly.

I am doing my 301 redirect from a custom 404 page. Now I got it working my question is more regarding how google would treat this. Cause we going to a 404 page would google just record it as a 40 page or would it actually record the 301? As i said I am new to this and have looked through google to try and find an answer to this.

Anyway any help or comment would be greatly appriciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice in this case could be:

1. If the page doesn't exist, but we have new one, with highly similar content, we can make 301 redirection, simply saying: "Moved permanently", which is instructing Google to actually take new URL on account and prioritize it.
2. If the page doesn't exist, and we actually have no idea why someone could type this link, as this URL never existed and is just wrong, then we serve 404 "Not Found". It simply means that the URL is wrong, and someone (or some other website) has fooled you to follow this link. You shouldn't automatically redirect user from this page, but place a link to the homepage instead, so user can choose his action.
3. If the page doesn't exist, and we know that we had this page, but it doesn't exist, and it will not exist in the future as well (we has simply decided that we will no longer have this page), then serve 410 "Gone" page, with a link to homepage as well, and let user decide.

HTTP codes, are not just a theory, it's a standard we should use. I noticed, that many 404 pages are served without correct HTTP response code, which only suggests that there is a poor development behind it.

More about HTTP response codes here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, a 301 redirect is the best way to retain "link juice" and should be used if the 404 page is referencing has a lot of external links, has substantial traffic, etc. 
Sending a generic 404 page straight to the home page is not ideal, as it may confuse the user. Allowing the 404 keeps the page from being repeatedly indexed and crawled by search engines.

Read more about it here: http://moz.com/learn/seo/http-status-codes.

Comment: Hey Melissa thanks for that. My 404 page redirects the page to the correct page if I have set it up before hand. All other pages are shown the 404 error. Just wasnt sure if the 301 from the 404 page was the valid way of doing a 301.

Answer (score 0):

it is not ok to redirect 404 page to another. it's better to correct it and show the old page. if it's impossible you should show 404 page and put some helpful links in it.

if you want to redirect to the correct one it's ok but the best way is to show display original page regardless of duplication. but you must use rel canonical to tell search engines  where is the correct version on the page.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en

Comment: The reason behind this is that we have created new website and most of the old pages from the site no longer exists or has been renamed. So I thought it would be better to do the 301 for the missing page via this solution.